# Server-side scheduling in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm looking for a simple server-side scheduling function in Node.js. I'm using Node.js, Express with PostgresSQL as my back-end and ejs as my templating solution. I'm new to coding and have only started a few months ago. The app takes betting orders from the users. The orders have an expiration date and are stored in a Postgres db.

I can't figure our how to create a server side scheduling job or function that checks these orders and send a message to the users that their order has expired. I can do it on the client-side with Ajax and setInterval but this is bad design in my opinion. Is there a simple way to do it on the server-side without overloading the server or hindering performance? The minimum expiration period is 30mins.

Comment: You can always cheat. Your orders have an expiry date, right? On the client side, if you load an order, you *know* when it should expire, so it's enough to run one setTimeout() and check after that time - there's no point in polling if you know the order won't expire for another hour.
Other than that, the Web platform offers several methods of sending asynchronous notifications: Server-Sent Events, WebSockets and Web Push notifications. Investigate whether any of those are required and/or useful for your case.